# FirebaseMessaging is null null and SendMessage fails because of it

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, firebase-admin

I have a code here where I want to use FireBase Admin to send push notifications to IOS and Android. I recieve token, title and body from method.

```
var message = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Message()
                {
                    Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification
                    {
                        Title = title,
                        Body = body
                    },
                    Token = DeviceToken.First(),
                    Apns = new ApnsConfig { Aps = new Aps { ContentAvailable = true, Sound = "default", Category = "test" } },
                    Android = new AndroidConfig { Notification = new AndroidNotification { ClickAction = "test" } }
                };

                var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;

                await messaging.SendAsync(message);
```

Comment: Have you initialised the SDK as outlined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk)?

Comment: @lee-m I have added the certificate, however I want to be able to send notifications to android and IOS. How do I do that ?

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with the code you've posted. Are you getting any errors when sending the notification or just not receiving them on the device?

Comment: @lee-m I Am not getting notifications on Iphone